# How to calculate a r-squared for a zero-truncated poisson mixed model (glmmTMB)

Tags: mixed-model, poisson-regression, glmmtmb, pseudo-r-squared

I am interested to calculate the pseudo-r-squuared for a zero-truncated poisson mixel model (using glmmTMB). The r.squaredglmm (package MuMin) gives a message that it can not calculate pseudo-r2 for zero-truncated poisson. Is there an easy work around or quick-and-dirty alternative?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What exactly do you mean by a pseudo $R^2?$ Once you get away from linear models with least squares fits, a generalization of $R^2$ is not straightforward, and there are multiple ways that can be defended. For instance, UCLA [lists](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/) many reasonable generalizations of $R^2$ to logistic regression.

Comment: Thanks for welcome. Actually, I thought that in case of mixed models, you speak of pseude-R2 and that  you might calculate R2, and indeed there are several approaches for that. I am not an expert, but just want to have a measure of explanation of variation of the fixed (marginal) and totla (conditional) effects if possible at all.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this answer is not too late.

The `performance` library offers a function `r2_zeroinflated()` which is supposed to compute "R2 for Zero-Inflated and Hurdle Regression". However, I couldn't get the feature to work.

If you'd settle for the pseudo-R2 based on a likelihood-ratio, you can use `MuMIn::r.squaredLR()`. For the hurdle model you will have to manually specify the `null` argument (*null* model). But otherwise it works fine.

Third option would be to somehow implement equations (1.17) or (1.18) from [this](https://uknowledge.uky.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1042&context=statistics_etds) dissertation. On page 10 the author refers to an article *Zero tolerance ecology: improving ecological inference by modelling the source of zero observations* by Martin et al. (2005). I looked it up, but unfortunately I couldn't find any measures of pseudo-R2 in it...

As the last one I'll share a link to [this page](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2018q1/026405.html) discussing calculation of conditional and marginal pseudo-R2 for glmmTMB objects but I'm doing it with a big big warning because they discuss a model *without* a zero-inflation part and *with* an observation-level random effect (OLRE). It isn't particularly what you have asked for. But if you can handle it, below I attach the script which is a bit clearer than in the link above and from which I removed the part where the variance of the OLRE term was calculated.

```
## fixed effects variance (manually)
model_linear.predictor = model.matrix(model) %*% fixef(model)$cond  ## "$cond" will extract coefficients from the conditional model; if you'd like to obtain coefficients from the zero-inflation part, use "$zi" instead
model_fixed.var = var(model_linear.predictor)

## random effects variance
model_randeff.var = unlist(VarCorr(model)$cond)

## originally the OLRE variance (model_OLRE.var) was calculated here

## the observation-level variance (it is distinct from the OLRE variance; the observation-level variance is the variance added by the distribution itself (a.k.a. distribution-specific variance))
model_beta0 = fixef(update(model, ~ 1))$cond  ## beta0 is the intercept from an intercept-only (y ~ 1) refit of the model
model_lambda = exp(model_beta0 + model_randeff.var/2)
model_ol.var = trigamma(model_lambda)

## total variance
model_total.var = model_fixed.var + model_randeff.var + model_ol.var  ## + model_OLRE.var

## conditional pseudo-R2 (takes both the fixed and random effects into account)
(model_fixed.var + model_randeff.var) / model_total.var

## marginal pseudo-R2 (considers only the variance of the fixed effects)
model_fixed.var / model_total.var
```

But again, although the script works technically well, this version of the script is definitely not the right solution for zero-inflated and hurdle models. It'd definitely need a modification.

Good luck with your analysis.